# Easily set multiple variables to false or true

Tags: javascript

I have multiple booleans defined in Javascript:

On toggle I would like to set these to false or true.

```
var categoryAdvertising = false;
var categoryInformArtation = false;
var categoryACA = false;
var categoryEntertainment = false;
var categoryInfluencing = false;
var categoryICE = false;
var categoryCommunication = false;
var categoryParticipation = false;
```

What is the best way to set these variables? Using an array?

Thanx in advance

Comment: If I had to manage these many boolean values, which are apparently related to each other in some manner, I would surely look at Flags/Bitmasks.

[Fortunately, MDN provides a very good example of using "Flags/Bitmaks":](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Examples)

Comment: @Golmaal funny thing about that article is that every flag is stored in a variable anyway, and javascript numbers take 8 bytes each.

Comment: @Esailija, Yes, but saving memory was never the key objective. I think the "flags/bitmasks" scheme makes the whole thing more compact and easy to manage.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use an object:

```
var category = {
    Advertising: false,
    InformArtation: false,
    ACA: false,
    Entertainment: false,
    Influencing: false,
    ICE: false,
    Communication: false,
    Participation: false
};

for( var key in category ) {
    category[key] = false;
}
```

To access object keys:

```
alert( category.Advertising );
```

Comment: add `hasOwnProperty` filter and get +1.

Comment: @c69: There's no need for `hasOwnProperty` on raw objects, unless someone has been mucking about with `Object.prototype`. If they have, take them out back, give them thirty lashes with a wet noodle, and have them write "I will not muck about with `Object.prototype` on the blackboard 300 times. :-)

Comment: +1, but given the usage scenario, I would also add an object method that sets the values to a parameter value.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - i agree, but frameworks are doing it _too often_.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder also, augmenting `Object.prototype` slows down every for..in loop (because of additional properties) which is already slow enough. jQuery purposely leaves hasOwnProperty out for example.

Comment: @c69: I've never seen a single framework that augmented `Object.prototype`. What one(s) are you talking about?

Comment: @Esailija: Yes, exactly. It causes all kinds of trouble, hence my suggesting "correcting" anyone who does it (er, unless they use `Object.defineProperty` and make the new property non-enumerable, but even *then*...).

Comment: However, its good advice to always use a `.hasOwnProperty` check on pure `for..in` loops anyway. The few cases where you don't want it don't justify to skip that line.

Comment: @jAndy: Maybe always note it when pointing people at `for..in`, but definitely don't always use it. Not in my view, anyway. Creates unnecessary complication if you know you're dealing with a raw object.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: the problem is, true raw objects are also only available with ES5 = `Object.create(null)`

Comment: @jAndy Well I want it to fail in environments where Object.prototype is augmented -- that way the code will break and people have to stop using Object.prototype, which speeds up all loops, making websites faster for people and saving electricity... global warming and all...

Comment: @jAndy: Don't want to get into an extended discussion here, but `Object.prototype` will never have any enumerable properties defined by the standard (see comment above about what to do to people who add them themselves). By "raw object" I mean one backed only by `Object.prototype`. Granted that's a bit of a loose term, but as you say, it was the closest one could get until recently.

Comment: @Esailija: "..people have to stop using Object.prototype..", even if I know what you mean, I seriously hope you are not not serious there.

Comment: @jAndy I mean people shouldn't add enumrable properties to Object.prototype... I hope that's clear enough from the context.. Y U NO CHAT? :P

Comment: @c69 that page explicitly says they don't augment object prototype

Comment: @c69: Prototype **doesn't** augment `Object.prototype`. For exactly this reason. It also augments some others (like `Array.prototype`, `Function.prototype`, and some others), but **not** `Object.prototype`. (The same goes for MooTools, which is either a fork of Prototype or "inspired by" Prototype depending on who you ask.) The DateJS library augments the `Date.prototype`. Augmenting those specialized prototypes is fairly common, and *mostly* innocuous although I don't think I'd advocate it. `Object.prototype`, on the other hand, must be left alone. Do you know of one that modifies it?

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely yes. You should either use an `Array` or if you need clear identifiers, use an `Object`.

```
var config = {
    categoryAdvertising: false,
    categoryInformArtation: false,
    categoryACA : false
    // etc
};
```

and then toggle all like

```
Object.keys( config ).forEach(function( opt ) {
    config[ opt ] = true; // or false
});
```

**Disclaimer**: This answer contains code that uses features not present in legacy browsers, the following links are suggestions of how to emulate those features in legacy browsers:

[Object#keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

Or even better, always use an ES5shim like:

https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim

Comment: Why use `Object.keys` and `forEach` rather than `for..in`? Seems over-complicated (and of course, fails on the browsers used by about half the world at present). :-) (I recommend [always warning](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118021/javascript-answers-using-es5-features-warn-or-not) when using ES5 features in answers.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: I don't agree. ES5 is more than common and has a "good" availabilty. I use it because of convinience + implicit `.hasOwnProperty` check here. I did mention about ES5 compatibilty half a year ago in most of my answers, IMO its time to ignore old'n'busted browsers.

Comment: @jAndy: I wouldn't call only working on half the desktops used for web browsing "good" availability. I'm not (by far) the only person who believes you must (at the moment) always warn when using ES5 features (see the link). Nice point about the `hasOwnProperty` check although there's no need for one here, but again, I just see no reason for the complexity of the intermediary array and callback.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: half the desktop browsers used? Now I need to ask for a source!

Comment: @jAndy: Again, see the link, full details there. Worldwide, at least 45% of people browsing the web are doing so with a browser that doesn't have ES5 (slightly lower if you exclude China) and thus requires that the programmer add the shim. To add the shim, they have to know they're dealing with ES5. Hence the statement about always warning people. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: I did read it, but I could not found the source for the numbers :(

Comment: @jAndy: In [my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/118023/134069), which links to the source (Net Applications, the same source used by IE6Countdown.com) and does the math. (+1 as of the edit, btw.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder [ES5 Shim](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim) = full support of both `Object.keys()`  and `Array.forEach` in IE6, or any newer non-es5 browser.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to set them all to `true` or `false` regularly, one wonders if you really need that many of them?

But if you do, use a function. Within the function, you can use a stacked assignment, e.g.:

```
function setVars(value) {
    categoryAdvertising =
        categoryInformArtation =
            categoryACA =
                categoryEntertainment =
                    categoryInfluencing =
                        categoryICE =
                            categoryCommunication =
                                categoryParticipation =
                                    value;
}
```

I was going to give you a second option, but [Esailija got there ahead of me](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8788007/157247) (+1).