# set a group of similarly named attributes to false

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In an AngularJS project, the view model has several properties associated with navigation that begin with the word "show".  There is a function that sets these to false when called:

```
var hideComponents = function() {
 vm.showAddress = false;
 vm.showEvent = false;
 vm.showAccount = false;
 //several others not displayed here
}
```

Is there a way to use a wildcard to set all of the properties that begin with the word "show" to false?  I was thinking something like this:

```
vm['show'*] = false;
```

but that syntax is not correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```
Object.keys(vm).forEach(key => {
  if (key.startsWith('show')) {
    vm[key] = false;
  }
})
```

Comment: This works great!  Is there a more concise way to exclude certain properties that start with the word "show" than this approach?  `if (key.startsWith('show') && key != 'showMenu' && key != 'showComponent')`?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution, using an object or array:

```
var vm.firstConfig = {
    showAddress: false,
    showEvent: false,
    showAccount: false
};

var vm.secondConfig = {
    showMenu: false,
    showThis: false,
    showThat: false
};

$scope.showHideComponents = function(value) {
    for (var i in vm.firstConfig) {
        vm.firstConfig[i] = value;
    }

    for (var i in vm.secondConfig) {
        vm.secondConfig[i] = !value;
    }
}
```

And if you're calling from HTML, do something like:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="toggle" ng-click="showHideComponents(toggle)" />
```

OR if you just want them on one line:

```
vm.showAddress = vm.showEvent = vm.showAccount = false;
```

Ref: [Easily set multiple variables to false or true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8787954/easily-set-multiple-variables-to-false-or-true)